# How to add leading zero in a number in Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am retrieving a column named removal_count in my query using COUNT() function. In result set the datatype of removal_count is BIGDECIMAL. I want to convert number into five digits. SO if value is less than five digits then it should be represented with leading zero's.

e.g 1) If removal count is 540 then display 00540
    2) If removal count is 60 then display  00060

If the removal count is integer/string value then I can add leading zero's using java expression :

```
--if removal_count is integer--
String.format("%05d",removal_count)

--if removal_count is string--
("00000"+removal_count).subString(removal_count.length())
```

Can we convert removal_count into string or integer ( from big decimal) so that I can use given java expression? Or else is there any way to add leading zero's in query itself?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could do it in two ways.

**Method 1**

Using **LPAD**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(num) AS(
  2  SELECT 540 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 60 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT num, lpad(num, 5, '0') num_pad FROM DATA;

       NUM NUM_P
---------- -----
       540 00540
        60 00060
         2 00002

SQL>
```

The WITH clause is only to build sample data for demo, in your actual query just do:

```
lpad(removal_count, 5, '0')
```

Remember, a **number** cannot have **leading zeroes**. The output of above query is a **string** and not a **number**.

**Method 2**

Using **TO_CHAR** and format model:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(num) AS(
  2  SELECT 540 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 60 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT num, to_char(num, '00000') num_pad FROM DATA;

       NUM NUM_PA
---------- ------
       540  00540
        60  00060
         2  00002

SQL>
```

**Update** : To avoid the extra leading space which is used for minus sign, use **FM** in the `TO_CHAR` format:

**Without FM:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1, '00000') num_pad,
  LENGTH(TO_CHAR(1, '00000')) tot_len
FROM dual;

NUM_PAD    TOT_LEN
------- ----------
 00001           6
```

**With FM:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1, 'FM00000') num_pad,
  LENGTH(TO_CHAR(1, 'FM00000')) tot_len
FROM dual;

NUM_PAD    TOT_LEN
------- ----------
00001            5
```

Comment: This type of question is already answered on stackoverflow                 How to display the leading zero's in a number of oracle

Comment: Hi @Lalit ,  small amendment. Method 1 is restricted to positive numbers. Method 2 works fine for negative numbers, but for positive numbers produces a leading blank for the missing sign. Any idea how to get rid of it (other than using substr)?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I verified the second method, and I find it working fine for both positive and negative numbers with + and - signs. Check LENGTH of the output for both it would be same.

Comment: @LalitKumarB here an example: `SELECT  lpad(-1, 5, '0') m1, length(to_char(1, '00000')) m2 num_pad FROM dual;`. The method one gives `000-1`. Method one work fine for both + and -; the problem I often fight with is the leading blank for positive numbers (demontrated with the length 6). It would be nice to have solution for *unsigned interger* giving always the length 5.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `LPAD` pl/sql function http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php.

```
removal_count = 540 
LPAD(TO_CHAR(removal_count), 5, '0');
Result: '00540'
```

Answer (score 1):

In sqlplus you can use col format:

SQL> select 540 aa, 540 bb from dual ;

```
    AA         BB
```

---

```
   540        540
```

SQL> col bb format 00000

SQL> /

```
    AA     BB
```

---

```
   540  00540
```

SQL>