# correct to_char date syntax to have trailing zeroes after milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My current query in oracle sql for getting a timestamp format is `TO_CHAR(c2.start_on,'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FF PM')`, it outputs the timestamp like this `25-11-20 07:00:13.36 PM`

However I want it to display the date in this way `25-11-20 07:00:13.360000000 PM`

What should I add in the timestamp format for this to be possible ?
I have tried doing it like this `HH:MI:SS.FM00000` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693668/19140215)
but it gives me the error. `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

what is the correct way to get the date in the desired format ?

Comment: If you do get that output, then `c2.start_on` is not a **date**; it is a **timestamp** or **timestamp with time zone** or similar. In Oracle, dates don't support fractional seconds, and the `ff` element in the format model would lead to an error if your data type was `date`. Also, the solution you are referencing is for formatting numbers as strings, why would you ever think that is relevant for formatting dates?

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding the column as a date rather than a timestamp. As for regarding why I was trying to follow the linked solution,  my understanding is that to_char converts a given input to a string so I figured the method of writing would be similar regardless of the datatype. It seems I was mistaken. Thank you

Comment: `to_char` is an overloaded identifier (different functions, same name). The argument can be number, date, timestamp, timestamp with time zone, etc. While there are many similarities, all these functions are different, they just share the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fractional seconds, you don't want a DATE, you want a TIMESTAMP. So here's a timestamp formatted with 6 digits of precision

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'HH:MI:SS.FF6') from dual;
```

[image]

If you have a date, you could convert it to a TIMESTAMP (using CAST AS TIMESTAMP), but better to look at updating your data model to use the proper type for the source column as starters.

[image]

Comment: Missing the `PM` at the end. Oracle should (but does not) throw an error if `hh` is used without the `AM` or `PM` element; otherwise it should require `hh24`.

Comment: Also the OP clearly has a timestamp as input - if he had a date, that format model would error out; and indeed, his output has fractional seconds.

Comment: This worked !  I mislabled the start_on timestamp column as a date format. Using `'HH:MI:SS.FF9'` gave me exactly how many trailing zeroes I wanted. Thank you !

Comment: @mathguy I hate having to guess what the OP is doing when it's easy for them to share code. I guess we need to train folks still on how to ask better questions.